# Tomcat7 Path Error? Unable to start service on port 8080 - Linux Mint 13

Tags: java, tomcat, environment-variables, tomcat7

I'm having difficulty running Tomcat7 as a service under Linux Mint 13. I'm installing from source rather than from the *apt-get repository*

Environment variables:

> **$JAVA_HOME:** /usr/lib/jvm/java
>
> **$JRE_HOME:** /usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_07
>
> **$PATH:**/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/tyler/bin:/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_07/bin:/home/tyler/bin:/usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_07/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java/bin
>
> **CATALINA_HOME**=/usr/local/tomcat

Any suggestions?

**When attempting to start the service (/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/startup.sh):**

> **Using CATALINA_BASE:**   /usr/share/tomcat7
>
> **Using CATALINA_HOME:**  /usr/share/tomcat7
>
> **Using CATALINA_TMPDIR:** /usr/share/tomcat7/temp
>
> **Using JRE_HOME:**        /usr/local/jdk1.7.0_07/jre
>
> **Using CLASSPATH:**    /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar

Error: Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost:8080
No other error dialogues appear.

Comment: Should it be `/usr/....` and not `./usr/...` ?

Comment: @hmjd: Good find, still no luck though. I've updated the body.

Comment: You're not saying what the new error is. When you say "from source", you do mean the binary package/tar ball though, right? And what's the command you're using?

Comment: @FrankPavageau: From a tar.gz file, using /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/startup.sh to (attempt) to start Tomcat7.

Comment: Firewall is currently disabled.

Comment: I assume executing startup.sh no longer gives an error. Check what's logged under /usr/share/tomcat7/logs, either in catalina.out or catalina.2012-09-23.log.

Comment: Output (catalina.out): /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/catalina.sh: 1: eval: /usr/local/jdk1.7.0_07/jre/bin/java: not found. So, my JRE_HOME variable is invalid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME are inconsistent (and JRE_HOME is not the same in your 2 examples). Anyway, you don't need both, as a JDK contains a JRE ( it's a super-set). So just set your JAVA_HOME and you should be ready to go.

Comment: Thank you, I don't mean to push my luck but do you know how to wipe out an environment variable? I've been searching to no avail. I've cleared it out in config files, but it's been set in update-alternatives --set java /usr/local/java/jre1.7.0_07/bin/java (sad, I know)

Comment: I'm trying to set $JRE_HOME to a null value.

Comment: unset JRE_HOME will remove it from the environment.